# Scipy Optimization TNC method, what does scale do ? solution to "unable to progress"?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, newtons-method

I am running multiple bounded optimizations with known gradient (100 to 300 Variables). Sometimes, TNC is returning "unable to progress".

For my objective function L-BFGS-B is much slower and outputs poor results compared to TNC. (*Maybe because TNC is better when number of variables are large)*
Using Basinhopping with L-BFGS-B and niter_success to 10, I am getting results close to TNC with 20x slower speed. When TNC returns "unable to progress", "L-BFGS-B" returns better results. So my current solution is to run Basinhopping when TNC fails with status 6 - "unable to progress".

It seems that "unable to progress" is returned when TNC is unable to reduce the objective function for x number of iterations. I played a little with the scale factor and inconsistently I got better results.

To my knowledge, Scale in an optimization problem let's the optimizer know which variable is more effective. I have this information and I believe this will reduce number of "unable to progress" I am getting. According to the docs,
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-tnc.html
***"The default scale array are up-low for interval bounded variables and 1+|x] fo the others"***. So it's upper bound - lower bound for variables which are bounded, unable to understand how unbounded is treated. **what is 1+|x]**  ?

Also, I manually calculated up - low and set unbounded to 1, this is returning different results every time I run the optimization with the same input. *(Strange ?)*

I also tried to look into the code, how TNC is handling scale, the spicy wrapper sends an empty array or the input array to C code https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/tnc/moduleTNC.c. In the C code I am unable to find where the scale array is created or how it's used. Also could not find when "unable to progress" is triggered. Can someone point me where I should look into ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved "unable to progress" thrown by TNC by scaling the input. If you are facing this issue, form a scale vector if you know which variables minimizes the objective function effectively.

Say X1 is more effective than X2, then your scale vector will be [100,2]. 
Use that to alter the bounds, the input data and the result (res.x).